# Using QGIS widget value-relation with PostgreSQL tables?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I am trying to implement types and subtypes to a layer of points that is stored in PostgreSQL and I wonder if it is possible to use Value Related Widget of QGIS, in PostgreSQL?

I followed the procedure explained at https://www.northrivergeographic.com/archives/qgis-3-2-drive-down-lists-aka-value-relation-widget

It works with shapefiles and geopackage, but it does not work with tables that are stored in PostgreSQL.

Comment: When you say 'doesn't work' is there an error message? What happens when you try to use a Postgres table? Your question tile is all in capitals, some won't like that as it's seen as *shouting*, can you edit your question and change the title to proper case please.

Comment: When I use the widget with postgresql tables, the relationship is not performed, and in the subtype field it shows me all the values. It does not filter the subtypes by type.